Connection between Real time evolution and Imaginary time evolution
Let $H = P$ be the Hamiltonian described by a Pauli operator $P$. The real time evolution according to H is
$$e^{-iPt}.$$
While the imaginary time evolution is
$$e^{-Pt}.$$
Consider the case $P=Y$. Than we have the y-axis rotation given by
$$e^{-iYt},$$
which should be unitary. However, it is also true that
$$Y = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i\\i & 0\end{pmatrix} = -i\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
If I substitute this matrix into the rotation operator I get
$$e^{-\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}}t$$
Isn't this an imaginary time evolution? But it can't be either a unitary and an ITE. What am I doing wrong?

Have you checked the eigenvalues of the matrix?

I guess they are +i and -i, the same of Y. Why? What does this mean?

Real (unitary) time evolution doesn't necessarily imply that the matrix elements of the propagator $e^{iHt}$ (or the wave functions/vectors that it operates on) have a non-zero imaginary part.  Since the eigenvalues of $i\sigma_Yt$ are purely imaginary, and the eigenvectors of $\sigma_Yt$ form an orthonormal basis, $e^{i\sigma_Y t}$ preserves the complex norm of the amplitudes of its eigenvectors, and encodes dynamics in their relative phases; this is the defining feature of unitary (von Neumann-entropy preserving) time evolution (imaginary time evolution does not preserve the complex norm.)

I see. May you explain this step by step as an answer?

@DanieleCuomo - Eigenvalues of $Y$ are $\pm1$, not $\pm i$.

The eigenvalues of the Pauli matrix $$\sigma_y= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array} \right)$$ are $+1$ and $-1$ with associated (normalized) eigenvectors $$\chi_+= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \begin{array} {c} 1 \\ i  \end{array}   \right), \quad \chi_-=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}   {c} 1\\ -i\end{array}    \right). $$ The spectral representation of $\sigma_y$ is thus given by $$\sigma_y = \chi_+ \chi_+^\dagger -\chi_- \chi_-^\dagger,$$ where $\chi_+\chi_+^\dagger$ and $\chi_-\chi_-^\dagger$ are the orthogonal projection operators on the two eigenspaces. An arbitrary  function $f$ of $\sigma_y$ takes the form $$f(\sigma_y)=f(1)\chi_+\chi_+^\dagger+f(-1)\chi_-\chi_-^\dagger.$$ For the special case of the unitary operator$f(\sigma_y)=\exp(-i\sigma_y t)$ one finds $$e^{-i \sigma_y t}=e^{-it} \chi_+\chi_+^\dagger + e^{it}\chi_-\chi_-^\dagger=\frac{e^{-it}}{2}\left(\begin{array} {cc} 1 &-i \\i & 1 \end{array}  \right)+\frac{e^{it}}{2}\left( \begin{array}     {cc}1 & i \\ -i &1\end{array}  \right) =\left( \begin{array} {cc} \cos t & -\sin t\\ \sin t & \cos t  \end{array}  \right) . $$
